# Given a cubic and a point S not on the cubic, how many tangent lines to F can we draw from S?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, cubics

Let $F\in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ be an irreducible homogeneous polynomial with total degree 3, defining a cubic in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Given a point $S$ on the projective plane but not on $\mathbb{V}(F)$, how many tangent lines to $F$ can we draw from $S$ ? By saying "a tangent line" I mean a line intersect with $F$ at some point with intersection multiplicity $\geqslant 2$.

For example, given a cubic with cusp: $y^3-x^2z=0$. If the point $S=[0,1,0]\notin \mathbb{V}(F)$, one can show that there are exactly 2 tangent lines through $S$: $x=0$ and $z=0$, both with intersection multiplicity 3.

So I guess although the number of tangent lines may not be a constant, we can conclude that:
$$ \sum I_P(F,l)=6 $$
where $l$ is the tangent line to F through S, P is the tangent point of $F$ and $l$, $I_P(F,l)$ stands for the intersection multiplicity. Does anyone know something about this question and proof? Any references are welcomed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Search for ‘dual curve’ or ‘polar curve’ and you’ll find an answer yourself.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Thank you, I will find myself.

Answer (score 2):

The really cool trick here is to introduce the correct definition: for a projective hypersurface $X = V(F) \subset \mathbf{P}_\mathbf{C}^n$ of degree at least $2$ we can define the *dual variety* as the projective variety lying in the dual projective space $$
   X^\ast :=\{ H \in \mathbf{P}^{n \ast}_\mathbf{C} \mid H\text{ intersects }X \text{ tangentially} \} \subset\mathbf{P}^{n\ast}_\mathbf{C}.
$$ $X^\ast$ can be seen to be a projective variety since it's quite explicitly given by the image of the Gauss map $$
 g_X : X \to \mathbf{P}^{n \ast}_\mathbf{C}
$$ sending the point $p \in X$ to its tangent hyperplane $$
 g_X(p) = \{\partial_{0}(F)(p)\cdot Y_0 + \ldots + \partial_n(F)(p)\cdot Y_n = 0\} \in \mathbf{P}^{n \ast}_\mathbf{C}
$$ where $Y_0,\ldots,Y_n$ are projective coordinates for $\mathbf{P}^{n \ast}_\mathbf{C}$ and $\partial_i(F) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial Y_i}$ denotes the partial derivative of the homogeneous polynomial $F$ with respect to the variable $Y_i$.

The study of the dual hypersurface $X^\ast$ is rather subtle and requires some machinery to properly understand - for instance, it turns out that $g_X$ is actually a birational map between $X$ and $X^\ast$; this follows fairly directly once you know $X^\ast \subset \mathbf{P}^{n\ast}_\mathbf{C}$ is also a hypersurface, by identifying $g_{X^\ast}$ as an inverse for $g_X$ on some dense open subset. Showing $X^\ast$ and $X$ have the same dimension requires some work though and is a statement that falls under the umbrella term "*reflexivity of projective varieties*".

Given all these black-boxes, if $X = V(F) \subset \mathbf{P}^2_\mathbf{C}$ is the vanishing locus of a homogeneous polynomial $F \in \mathbf{C}[x,y,z]$ of degree $d > 1$ and $p \in \mathbf{P}^2_\mathbf{C}\setminus X$, as in your situation, we see that $$
   \{H \in \mathbf{P}^{n \ast}_\mathbf{C} \mid p \in H\} \cap X^\ast \subset \mathbf{P}^{n \ast}_\mathbf{C}
$$ is the intersection of $X^\ast$ with the projective line $$
   L = \{H \in \mathbf{P}^{n \ast}_\mathbf{C} \mid p \in H\} \subset \mathbf{P}^{n \ast}_\mathbf{C}
$$ of lines passing through $p \in \mathbf{P}^2_\mathbf{C}$. Since $g_X$ is a birational map, we see that (if $L$ is chosen so that $L \cap X^\ast$ lies in an open subset on which $g_X$ is an isomorphism - i.e. $L$ is chosen generically) $$
   \# X^\ast \cap L = \# X \cap g^{-1}_X L
$$ and since $g_X$ is quite visibly a morphism of degree $d-1$, $g^{-1}_X L \subset \mathbf{P}^2_\mathbf{C}$ is a hypersurface of degree $d-1$. By Bézout's theorem, this means the number of points you're interested in is (with multiplicities)$$
   \deg X \cdot \deg g_X^{-1}L = d \cdot (d-1)
$$ which equals $6$ if $d=3$ :D

Where I learned this from is Eisenbud's and Harris' textbook *3264 and all that* and I think it's a great read in case you're interested in learning more about intersection theory :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I am a new hand in intersection theory, and I will learn 3264 first !  :)

Answer (score 2):

As $F$ is irreducible, no information is lost in considering the likewise cubic polynomial $f(x,y)=F(x,y,1)$. The points you are looking for satisfy the equations $f(p)=0$ and $f'(p)[S-p]=0$.

Now the remainder $f'(p)[p]-3f(p)$ is a quadratic polynomial of degree $2$, so that the second equation can be reduced to degree $2$. Now return to the homogeneous version to find that the number of solutions counting multiplicities is indeed $6$.

This generalizes, if $F$ is homogeneous of degree $d$, then $f'(p)[S]$ and $f'(p)[p]-d\cdot f(p)$ both have degree $d-1$, so the tangency equation can be reduced to degree $d-1$ and the Bezout number is $d\cdot(d-1)$.

Not considered in this short argument is that the reduced tangency condition could have a degree smaller than $d-1$ (but I suspect that the irreducibility of $F$ prevents that).

Comment: Thank you for your clear argument! I think you are right and let me check the details :)!

Comment: Most geometric algebra over the complex field can be reduced to differential calculus. It is only if you switch the underlying field that you need clear algebraic ideas so that the results remain the same or deviate in clearly understandable ways.